# How to select first empty cell in a column?

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe

```
DF1:
     Y1    Y2     Y3
1   1-5  6-10  11-15    #age-groups
2    3    2      2      #number of people per age-group

DF2:
ID  Age-Group           
 1    NA
 2    NA
 3    NA
 4    NA
 5    NA
 6    NA
 7    NA
```

and I want to add the data from  DF1 in the Age-Group column of DF2:

```
DF2:
ID  Age-Group
 1    1-5
 2    1-5
 3    1-5
 4    6-10
 5    6-10
 6    11-15
 7    11-15
```

So far I have a loop:

```
for (i in 1:3)    #number of columns in DF1
{number=DF1[2,i]  #stores the number of times Age-Group 1-5 is repeated (3)
DF2[1:number,2]=DF1[1,i] #attach the 1-5 label to the first 3 cells
```

This loop will work to apply the first age-group 1-5, but when I move to the next label, 6-10... How do I fill the 2 empty cells starting at row 4? As of right now, the loop will always start at row 1. My dataframe is much larger than that, which is why a loop would be much better.

Comment: Maybe `DF2[, 2] <- rep(DF1[1, ], DF1[2, ])` will do what you're after... your question's not entirely clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I will assume df1's columns are not factors. A neat way to enforce this would be to use:

```
    df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)
```

You can use the function rep(). It's important to note that rep() accepts vectors as input for both it's first and second arguments, so a for loop is unnecessary here. Instead:

```
    df2[, 1] <- unlist(rep(df1[1, ], df1[2, ]))
```

Here, we are telling rep() to repeat the first age group "1-5" 3 times, "6-10" 2 times, etc. The output of rep() will be a list, so unlist() can be used to convert
a list into a vector.

Comment: `rep` won't return a list

Comment: I thought it should because the inputs `df1[1, ]` and `df1[2, ]` are both lists, essentially, and the return type should be the same as the first argument.

Comment: @Scott thank you for your answer! it was straight forward.

Answer (score -1):

I think Scott's answer is best. Here is a way using a for loop explicitly:

```
a=data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(t(DF1)))
{
   b<-data.frame(AGE=rep(t(DF1)[i,1],(as.numeric(t(DF1)[i,2]))))
   a<-rbind(a,b)
}
```